# How to RAISE NOTICE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using pgAdmin, and I want to have a simple raise notice; referring to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html), I entered `RAISE NOTICE 'note';` and got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RAISE"
LINE 1: RAISE NOTICE 'note';
```

The only way I could manage to get an output was by using this (which I don't understand well either):

```
DO $$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'note';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And got this output:

```
NOTICE:  note
DO
```

Could someone please explain this?

Comment: I know that I'm a year to late, but do you need it to be a notice or could you use `\echo message`?

Comment: @some I don't remember what exactly I needed it for; I guess I needed something to show the progress. I don't know about \echo (or the difference between that and a notice) and if it could be enough for that purpose.

Comment: A **NOTICE** is typically used in functions that want to send a notice or warning to the user, or to print information during function development. To inform the user about what is happening in a long script, there are the built-in functions `\echo` and `\warn`. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap `RAISE` into a procedure

```sql
create procedure raise_notice (s text) language plpgsql as 
$$
begin 
    raise notice '%', s;
end;
$$;
```

and call it in SQL

```
call raise_notice('note');
```

For PG version before 11 create a function that `returns void` with the same body and `select` from it in SQL

```
select raise_notice('note');
```

Answer (score 10):

`RAISE` is a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) command and can only be used inside PL/pgSQL. The [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command creates an anonymous PL/pgSQL block (something like a "temporary procedure") and therefor you can use RAISE inside that PL/pgSQL code.

`RAISE` can **not** be used in plain [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html), that's why you get the error

Comment: Then, I have to wrap raise notice in a function, right?

Comment: Why do you need `raise notice` at all? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with it?

Comment: @Belayer I'm going to have a large sql file and I want a message printed after each command is run.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for how to **RAISE NOTICE**, but after reading the following from the comments to another answer, I want to inform you about another solution.

> **Belayer**: *Why do you need raise notice at all? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with it?*
>
> **Yusif**: *I'm going to have a large sql file and I want a message printed after each command is run.*

If your goal is to display messages to the user running the script using the command line tool [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html) or use `PSQL Tool` from [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/), the following built in commands of `psql` might be of interest:

- [`\echo text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-ECHO) Prints the evaluated arguments to **standard output**, separated by spaces and followed by a newline.
- [`\warn text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-WARN) Identical to `\echo` except that the output will be written to **standard error**.
- [`\out file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-OUT) Outputs all query results, command responses, and notices, but not error message, to a file. With this active you can choose what to show the user.
- [`\qecho text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-QECHO) Identical to `\echo` except that the output will be written to the **query output channel**, as set by `\out`.

Comment: +1 Although not answering the question I asked, seems like this solution is what I actually needed. Thanks.